# How to change terminal font color in PyCharm?

Tags: terminal, colors, fonts, pycharm

I want to set my terminal color scheme, such that I will have black text on light background (white or light yellow for example).

I changed "Console Colors" settings, such as Background, Standard output, and System output, under Editor > Colors & Fonts > Console Colors, but I keep running into the same problem.

If I change Background color to let's say white. It also changes text (Standard output and my user input to the same color). I can't figure out, which setting controls the color of the font, which appears in the terminal window. In fact, it appears that font color is the same as background color, which is confusing to me. I would expect to be able to independently control background color, and font color, which to me represents "Foreground".

<[image: my terminal window screen shot]

Comment: I've posted a solution for pycharm 2022 at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50184877/how-do-i-change-terminal-prompt-color-in-pycharm/75166640#75166640

Answer (score 3):

Changing colour in

> Preferences->Editor->Color Scheme->Console Colors->Standard Output

should change the terminal font's colour.

Comment: This has no effect. The standard output color remains the same as the background colour in the linux version of pyharm. Are the any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: I changed the Console > Background > Background colour to make it work on the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it happened on Windows. If yes then it is affected/controlled by Windows registry. Try one of the following method:

1. Open Windows cmd and from drop down menu selects defaults. Then change the Text and Background colors to match your choice in PyCharm. The problem occurs if you have different color settings in Windows cmd instead of default.
2. Delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console key from Windows registry.

[More information available on this link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145236?_ga=2.39644267.93297776.1595226221-1100657204.1579966063)

Comment: step one was all I needed. Had the wrong colour selected for background in the windows console defaults; had just followed through with a make your console look like Ubuntu post and clicked one of the radio buttons for background text.

Answer (score 0):

To configure color and font scheme for consoles

1. Make sure you are working with an editable scheme.
2. Open the IDE Settings, and under Colors&Fonts, scroll through the list of components, and select the ones related to consoles:

   - Console Colors
   - Console Fonts
3. In the right-hand pane, click the desired component in the list, and change color settings and font type:
   [See Image of how to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFVcG.png)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but these are exactly the settings that I have been using to adjust my console colors. The problem which I see has to do with the following: the two settings which appear to affect colors are "Console > Background > Background" and "Standard output > Foreground". If let's say I set them both to white, I get almost what I want, which is white background. The problem is the text is also white, so it blands completely with the background. So for example, in my screenshot - background is white, so is the text. Grey area represents "Standard output > Foreground".

Comment: The question was for terminal, not console.

Comment: I've posted a solution for pycharm 2022 at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50184877/how-do-i-change-terminal-prompt-color-in-pycharm/75166640#75166640