# How do I change terminal prompt color in Pycharm

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

I searched Google for an hour and there was no satisfactory answer for this.

I'm using Pycharm 2018.1 and I want to set my default terminal prompt more noticeable so that I can read it with much ease.

i.e, I want "(venv) C:\User\myname\PycharmProjects\projectname>" to be green or something but not the rest of the input & output.

I've tried changing the setting at File>Settings>Editor>Color Scheme>Console Colors. When I change [Standard output]'s [foregound] to any color, it does change the prompt's color but it also changes the rest of the lines like user's input or the result output. (you'll have to open a new terminal to see the change) 
So that's not what I want.

The closest one was [How to change terminal font color in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628348/how-to-change-terminal-font-color-in-pycharm) but the comment here also points out that the setting mentioned here is for the console, not terminal prompt.

What I want to do is the one like this on Pycharm. [image]

Comment: The thing you want to change in Console Colors is "User Input".

Comment: @l'L'l Tested. It's not. I'm not sure 'Console color' is a right place to do this. It's terminal. Not a console. Beside, it seems to follow MS cmd's commands where 'dir' works but 'ls' doesn't.

Comment: Is that the actual window of it above, or something you grabbed elsewhere? It says "Powershell"...

Comment: @l'L'l Of course it's something i just pasted it from somewhere. I want something like that on my Pycharm terminal.

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm find File > Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S) > Editor > Color Scheme > Color Fonts > Console > User Input > Foreground

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efSW5.png)

Answer (score 0):

You won't find the settings for this in pycharm because its using Windows Powershell for its terminal.

You need to change the settings for Windows Powershell.

There is a great youtube video on this at https://youtu.be/PwhGKn3ghy4

Please note: To change OperatorColor in the file (content below) refer to it as Operator

I personally added the following to Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 as explained in
the video:

```
$colors = @{} 
$colors['Operator'] = [System.ConsoleColor]::Cyan
$colors['Parameter'] = [System.ConsoleColor]::Cyan
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors $colors
```

This works when powershell is invoked by pycharm in a terminal.